# Spring boot 2.7 migrating spring.factories into imports file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I updated the project from spring boot 2.6 to 2.7 and I'm having trouble registering the TestExecutionListener class. Before it was registered in spring.factories

`org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener = com.example.MyListener`

Release notes says about move spring.factories into imports file
*If you have created your own test-slices, you should move the registration from spring.factories to the new place under META-INF/spring/.imports*

Now, i have no idea how do it. I've tried many options and configrations and no one works well for me.

Comment: What have you tried? Seems pretty straight forward to me. Create a `.imports` file in `META-INF/spring` in your `src/test/resources` .

Comment: Yes, I know that about create a file. So, I created it and then spring context load this file but any test don't invoke this listener.
When I used `spring.factories` with content works well. `org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener = com.example.MyListener`

Comment: I more think, earlier in the logs you could see an entry about loading the listener class by SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper, with `.imports` configuration are loaded only default listeners

Comment: Please add the link to where you found the change.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes Loading auto-configurations from spring.factories is deprecated.

Comment: You should read again... That is for auto-configuration **not** related to registering test execution listeners. So no `spring.factories` isn't deprecated but only for registering auto-configuration classes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved this problem, thx @M.Deinum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read the documentation again. The `spring.factories` is deprecated for

1. Auto-configuration classes
2. Test Slices

but not for registering `TestExecutionListener` instances for the tests.